# Cannot find element of Fragment directly after placing the Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

G'Day,
The problem is simple, in the `onResume()` method of the AppCompatActivity im replacing a Fragment and want to change some values of its children directly after this.

For Example:

```
public void onResume(){
    Fragment FR = new Fragment();
    FragmentTransaction FT = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    FT.replace(containerID, FR); //The Container is a FrameLayout
    FT.commit();

    findViewById(R.id.someTextView).setId(SomeID); //This throws a NullPointerException

}
```

To be Exact:  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.View.setId(int)' on a null object reference`

Any Idea how to find my View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use commitNow in stead of commit.
The fragment isn't actually attached in place after the commit instruction.
commitNow will execute the commit synchronously and you should be able to find the view afterward.

Answer (score 0):

As getView() works only after onCreateView(), you can't use it like above..